# Mocked variable for unittest not working in decorated function in flask

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking, nose2

I have a decorator that needs a test similar to this:

```py
# code.py
from flask import request, current_app

def some_decorator(f):
  @wraps(f)
  def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
    if current_app.config['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'test':
      pass

    if request.method == 'POST':
      pass

    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  return decorated_function
```

With test:

```py
import mock

@mock.patch('flask.request')
def test_some_decorator(mock_req):
  mock_req.method = 'POST'

  function = lambda x: x
  decorated_function = some_decorator(function)

  function(1)
```

Now the thing is, the mocked `request.method` value does not get overridden with `'POST'` mocked value but instead ends up with `'GET'` which I think is a default one.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I guess your `decorated_function` is doing something else, because the shown one does nothing but return the original function, right?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen yup, just did that for showing the structure

Comment: Have you tried `@mock.patch('code.flask.request')`?